# Write problem - lossing the original data

Tags: java, file-io, append

Every time I write to the text file I will lose the original data, how can I read the file and enter the data in the empty line or the next line which is empty?

```
public void writeToFile()
{   

    try
    {
        output = new Formatter(myFile);
    }
    catch(SecurityException securityException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error creating file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error creating file");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    String number = "";
    String name = "";

    System.out.println("Please enter number:");
    number = scanner.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter name:");
    name = scanner.next();

    output.format("%s,%s \r\n",  number, name);
    output.close();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must [open the file for append](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score 1):

You need to open `myFile` in append mode. See [this link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/java-append-to-file.shtml) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use the [append](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) option.

This code can write data in the default platform encoding:

```
  private static void appendToFile() throws IOException {
    boolean append = true;
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TextAppend.txt", append);
    Closeable resource = out;
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
      resource = pw;
      pw.format("%s,%s %n", "foo", "bar");
    } finally {
      resource.close();
    }
  }
```

There are a number of classes you can wrap around an [OutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) to achieve the same effect. Be aware that the above approach can [lose data](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_lossyconversions) when the code is run on a platform that doesn't use a Unicode default encoding (like Windows) and may produce different output on different PCs.

One case in which care is need is if the encoding inserts a [byte order mark](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM). If you wanted to write lossless Unicode text in `UTF-16` marked with a little-endian BOM, you would need to check the file for existing data.

```
private static void appendUtf16ToFile() throws IOException {
  File file = new File("TextAppend_utf16le.txt");
  String encoding = (file.isFile() && file.length() > 0) ?
      "UnicodeLittleUnmarked" : "UnicodeLittle";
  boolean append = true;
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
  Closeable resource = out;
  try {
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, encoding);
    resource = writer;
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
    resource = pw;
    pw.format("%s,%s %n", "foo", "bar");
  } finally {
    resource.close();
  }
}
```

Supported encodings:

- [Java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- [Java 5](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

We're you've got: `new Formatter(myFile);` you'll want to use `new Formatter(new FileWriter(myfile, true)`. The true indicates you want to append to that file.